# Intellij / Websphere run config says "address localhost:8880 is already in use"

Tags: intellij-idea, localhost, websphere, socketexception

This is my first attempt at creating a Websphere Local run configuration in Intellij and obviously I need some help.

First question: is Websphere supposed to be running when I run the configuration?

Second question: when I run the configuration and Webshpere is not running Intellij will say 'cannot ping localhost:8880', so probably Websphere should be running. When I start Websphere and then start the Intellij run config it says "address localhost:8880 is already in use" and then "Unable to open debugger port (127.0.0.1:62019): java.net.SocketException: 'socket closed'".

Here is my setup:

[image]

Third question: from the Websphere admin console I got that port 8880 is configured as the SOAP_CONNECTOR_ADDRESS. Is Intellij supposed to use that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me:

- Go to run/debug configuration and click on +
- Choose Remote (and not Websphere Server)
- Change port to the port you want to use(I choose 7777)

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question: no, if you want to start the server from IntelliJ, you should first check the server is stopped.

For solving the problem: Have you checked if WebSphere is running as a service automatically?

For doing it on Windows:

1. Open a "File Explorer" window
2. Right click on "My Computer"
3. Click on "Manage"
4. Click on "Services and Applications"
5. Click on "Services"
6. Look for "IBM WebSphere Application Server"
7. Check if it's running and stop it, change it to manual if you want to start server from IntelliJ without repeating this whole process everytime you log in Windows.