# IntelliJ Websphere Server Local, Error running 'Local Deploy': Address localhost:9080 is already in use

Tags: intellij-idea, websphere

I seem to be doing something wrong in my run configuration for IntelliJ. I cannot run the server on the port 9080 because another app has to use the port 9080 and it's not up to me what port that app uses. So please don't tell me to kill the app using the port 9080. This is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33437404/intellij-websphere-run-config-says-address-localhost8880-is-already-in-use)

With the other app running I can start up the server via command line or using an external tool in IntelliJ however I cannot start it though a run configuration. My server requires the other app to be running locally to do local testing however I cannot debug the app due to this extremely annoying issue. IntelliJ is simply picking the port 9080 out of some configuration and checking that port all on its own and deciding to not try starting the server and then somehow at some point deciding to check the port which of course wont be available. Is there a setting that I'm missing or is there another way to handle this so that way I don't run into this issue?

[image: Configuration options]
In local deploy there is not an option to change the port number.

Comment: You can change the port in Run/Debug Configuration. Have you tried looking  there?

Comment: @Andrey No I can't. Local does not have the option to change the port. Remote does but local does not. Do I need to do a remote configuration even though it is local?

Comment: Try changing the port in server.xml file - IDE checks it when setting the port, like `<httpEndpoint httpPort="9130" id="defaultHttpEndpoint" host="localhost"/>`. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-120292#focus=streamItem-27-699895-0-0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @Andrey's comments the solution turned out to be the server.xml is all that IntelliJ checks and doesn't load the bootstrap.properties right off the get go. So if you are filling in the httpPort number via bootstrap.properties, server.env, or any dynamically loaded properties, IntelliJ will use the default 9080. The solution here was then to simply hardcode the httpPort in `<httpEndpoint httpPort=9081 ... />` for local testing